# Прокручивание цифр как на одноруком бандите

Tags: javascript

Делаю красивую прокрутку цифр, как на барабане однорукого бандита, но что-то не получается. Использую для эффекта js плагин https://github.com/HubSpot/odometer

Есть число исходное заданное в элементе, каждую секунду к нему надо добавлять +1

Параметры odometer

```
window.odometerOptions = {
  format: '(,ddd,ddd)'
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="odometer">1110</div>
```

Код JS:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var count = $('.odometer').text().replace(/\r?\n/g, "");
    console.log(count);
    var count_new = parseInt(count)+1;
    console.log(count_new);

    $('.odometer').html(count_new);

},5000);
```

Получается какая-то злобная штука потом в консоли

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том,что цифорка не меняется, а начинает тикать 2,3,4,5 ... а потом длинная цифра выводится...

Comment: Очень интересный баг. Возможно, что-то связанное с конвертацией типов. Можете запилить пример в сниппете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var count = parseInt($('.odometer').text().replace(/\r?\n/g, ""));
    /*
    * а лучше
    * let start_count = 1110;
    * let count = start_count;
    * */
    setInterval(function(){
        count++;
        $('.odometer').html(count);
    },5000);
```

Comment: работает спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Одометр работает с помощью innerHTML, чтобы установить новую цель для внутренней работы компонента. Ваш код постоянно сбрасывает это значение, и это вводит в заблуждение код одометра, заставляя его превышать свои пределы безопасности и произвести неожиданные результаты.